# Gradle build not updating snapshot version in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build, build.gradle

I have 2 projects A and B. project B uses A as runtime dependency (I use Gradle for it). so whenever I update something in A and do gradle clean install and do Gradle clean build on project B, the changes are visible in project B as jar is updated in .m2 folder.

But recently when I am making changes in A and doing the same process I can't see these changes in project B.

Any Idea what am I missing?

P.S. I am using IntelliJ

Comment: Does it help to run "Reload" from Gradle tool window?

Comment: No, It does not help.

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after running "Reload"?

Comment: I found the mistake I did. I did not update the snapshot version in build.gradle file. so Gradle kept the previous version.